# How can I identify what is slowing down my mac when nothing is eating up CPU?

Tags: macos, mac, performance

Sometimes I'll have characters appearing slowly on screen, an unwelcome beach ball or pages like google images will freeze while scrolling.

When this happens often all seems calm in activity monitor, nothing is above 20% CPU, so what can I do to diagnose the cause of slowness or unresponsiveness?

Comment: Check memory usage - you are possibly short of RAM

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple more things you can check-

1. Hard-drive space. Go to the Apple Menu >> About This Mac >> More Info >> Storage and check how much space you've taken up. Also consider looking at booting to recovery mode and using Disk Utility to check the health of your hard-drive
2. (Mal|Crap)ware. Go to the spotlight search and open the Console app. Look to see if a program is constantly opening and crashing. Malware checks can be done by inspecting the root and user library folders (Input Managers, LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons).

(I would use a comment for this, but I do not have enough rep yet)